# PHP how to make form disappear after pressing submit button

Tags: php, forms

Lets say i have a form that asks for name and exam result. Id like to make the form disappear and display another div when the user hits submit.

heres the form code

```
<form action="exam.php" method="post" id = "coursedata" class="form-horizontal">
<fieldset>
<legend>Please Complete the Details</legend>
     <div class ="form-group">
      <label for="name" class="control-label col-xs-2">Student name</label>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="20" class="form-control" autofocus required pattern = "[A-Z][a-z]+( [A-Z][a-z]+)?" title="Please enter a name (Surname optional) with First Letter capitalised">
      </div></div>
    <div class ="form-group">
      <label for="CA1" class="control-label col-xs-2">Assessment One</label>
     <div class="col-xs-6">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" min = "0" max = "100"name="CA1" id="CA1" size="3" maxlength ="3" onkey ="limit(this);" onkeyup="limit(this);" required>
    </div></div>
<div class="buttonarea">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name = "Submit">
        <input type="reset" value="Clear the Info">
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: You need JavaScript for this. You also need to learn the difference between server-side and client-side. That's *very* important in the world of web development.

Comment: Why need for javascript? And why +3 for this, when of COURSE no javascript is needed here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortest way (asuming that form and exam.php are the same files...):

```
<?php
    if (!isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
?>
Your form code
<?php
    }
    else {
        // form engine
        echo "<div>SUCCESS</div>";
    }
?>
```

Hope it helps :). PS. This is a strict answer to Your question, whether there are many other questions, like how to handle form, how to verify it, etc. But this is another side of answered coin ;). Best regards :).

Comment: Seems on the right path but when i add it, it just always displays the success text rather than show the form.

Comment: And what about letter case? Is name="submit" the same as $_POST['submit']? It should work :).

Comment: yeah there both in Caps. Is it working off type, value or name? There all in caps anyway. heres the full paste. http://pastebin.com/Ffy3fF0M

Comment: Thx for the paste. Everything looks alright... It is name that is considered. Try to make both lowercase. And make form action="" (left it blank). Maybe this will help. And, stupid idea, but maybe the POST[submit] is always there? Try not to refresh page (as it keeps POST data) , but write url from the beginning and hit enter. Please, write if there are still any problems :).

Comment: if i remove the ! from the isset it appears but doesnt dissappear when form is filled in. Ill try the other things now. edit --- yeah 100% it was the lower case. lesson learned and much appreciated. Scratching my head all day trying.

Comment: Ok great :). Thx for aproving answer, and if any questions, feel free to write! :).

Comment: I did not know this was even possible

Answer (score 1):

Use [jQuery](http://jquery.com) for this (JavaScript library).

Copy this in your `head` section

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('button[type="submit"]').click(function(){
                $("#coursedata").hide();
                return false;        
            })
        })
    </script>
```

Comment: ok, then try Jacek's solution, just replace `!isset($_POST['Submit']` with `!isset($_POST['name']` or whatever required variable.